# Example of when FWER control should be preferred to FDR control

Tags: multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

In the [Benjamini & Hochberg paper (1995)](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.2517-6161.1995.tb02031.x) which introduces the False Discovery Rate (FDR), the authors compare the FDR to the Family-Wise Error Rate (FWER):

> Often the control of the FWER is not quite needed. The control of the FWER is important when a conclusion from the various individual inferences is likely to be erroneous when at least one of them is. This may be the case, for example, when several new treatments are competing against a standard, and a single treatment is chosen from the set of treatments which are declared significantly better than the standard.

But assume I pick the treatment at random from the set of significantly better treatments, wouldn't the FDR then be more appropriate for controlling erroneous selection? Can you give an example for when FWER control should be preferred to FDR control?